# Сколько правил  должен знать грамотный человек?

Tags: правила

Действительно, можно ли сосчитать все орфографические правила, которые нам предлагают выучить, или хотя бы порядок их определить? Хорошо бы еще  построить  график возрастания их количества  начиная  с 1956 года? А что если это будет экспонента!  Тогда их число неизбежно приблизится к критической отметке, и что тогда?  И если ли вообще какие-нибудь планы и прогнозы в этой области?

Спасибо всем,  кто захочет поделиться своим мнением  по этому «количественному вопросу», а пока вашему вниманию предлагается сказка.

СКАЗКА

Один шах очень любил слушать рассказы путешественников и держал большой штат писцов, чтобы их записывать. Но вот беда –  записанные истории так отличались от устных, что их  порой было не узнать. Тогда шах позвал главного визиря и спросил его совета. Визирь сказал, что  хорошо бы составить правила для письма.  Шах обрадовался и наградил его дорогими подарками.

Правила были составлены, и если писец нарушал их, ему отрубали голову. Теперь книги стало читать намного удобнее. Но чем больше записывалось разных историй, тем больше требовалось правил, и тем меньше становилось писцов, знающих эти правила, и в конце концов  не осталось ни одного.

Шах рассердился и снова позвал своего  министра.  «О великий шах, – сказал  визирь, – надо набрать новых писцов, отменить все правила и оставить только одно. Но при этом все  остальные правила должны следовать из этого Главного правила».

Так и было сделано, и с помощью только одного Правила было написано очень много интересных рассказов. А писцов с тех пор стали называть писателями, потому что они стали свободными и уважаемыми людьми.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Указ 1

1. Запрещается применять правила неясного происхождения, не имеющих связей с Главным правилом и не следующих непосредственно из Главного правила.
2. Провести перепись  всех правил, а также  подсчитать их общее количество.
3. Круг лиц, ответственных  за нарушение указа, может быть расширен. Мера ответственности указана выше.

20 июля 2014 года  И. о. Главного визиря  (подпись неясная)

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду под "грамотный человек"? Писать без ошибок вообще, невозможно, слов исключений масса и их все знать невозможно, ни говоря уже об описках и прочих человеческих факторах. Тот кто пишет диктанты без ошибок не обязательно сможет составить грамотный текст, ровно как писатель необязательно соблюдает все правила орфографии и пунктуации. Это если не вспоминать про устную речь, где даже профессионал обе ноги поломает, пока разберётся с конкретным произношением.

Comment: А сколько ангелов должны помещаться на кончике иглы?

Comment: Если идеал, как в ЕГЭ, принять за 100 баллов, то грамотный человек - это где-то около 70 баллов (условная, конечно, оценка). Кстати, действительно, можно различит два вида грамотности: во-первых, по наличию орфографических и пунктуационных ошибок; во-вторых, по умению составить стилистически грамотный текст. Иногда разница достаточно ощутима, причем встречаются оба варианта.

Comment: ПРИКАЗЫВАЮ: 1. Принять СКАЗКУ как образец - для исполнения. 2. Ответственность возложить на Галактиона 3. Контроль за ситуацией оставляю за собою. СОФИЯ.

Comment: Указ №1 - в дополнении к ответу.

Comment: София! Вы - умница! Вместо Ливанова надо Вас поставить!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и ни одного правила не знать и писать практически без ошибок. Можно вызубрить всего Розенталя и Лопатина и не уметь применить эти знания на практике. Всё индивидуально.

Правила орфографии и пунктуации - это этикет на бумаге. Условность, без неё можно и обойтись, но её соблюдение делает жизнь (чтение) проще. В домашней обстановке, если никому не мешаешь, можно сеть как угодно, но если обедаешь в приличном обществе, будь добр хотя бы не чавкать. Так и с грамотностью. В рунете считается плохим тоном указывать кому-либо на его ошибки в письме, так как если условность, мешает непосредственному общению, то такая условность ни к чему. Однако, если текст претендует на серьёзность, то наличие ошибок будет затруднять восприятие мысли.

Если говорить лично обо мне, то я делаю сравнительно много ошибок, так что не показатель. В реальности если брать именно выученные в школе правила, а не запомненные образы слов и грамматических конструкций, то я использую правила: "-тся - -ться", "дефисное и слитное написание сложных слов" и "«который» выделяется запятыми". Во всех остальных случаях, в общем-то правила не использую.

Comment: Мне как раз хотелось донести до аудитории, что правила в их классическом виде устарели, что не должны они напоминать мантры или священные гимны. Каждую орфографическую тему следует давать не в  виде правил-формулировок, а как определенное количество информации, обладая которой пишущий выбирает правильную форму. В конечном счете он приходит к тем же правилам, но при этом понимает их разумность, свободно ориентируется в решении при наличии вариантов. Именно такое представление орфографии может обеспечить естественную свободу общения, тогда и  правила перестанут  казаться условностью.

Comment: @София, правила немного устарели, но не в том смысле, что имеете в виду вы. Как систематизация графического узуса, что Розенталь, что Лопатин неплохи. Правила - это таблица Менделеева правописания. Схема эта безусловно нужная и важная, совсем без неё будет тяжело, но зная только её химиком не станешь.

Обучение грамотному письму - это уже раздел методологии, к которой правила правописания имеют лишь косвенное отношение. Педагогика, в моём понимании, вообще ближе к искусству, чем к науке.

Comment: Никто не возражает против Розенталя и Лопатина, пусть существуют в виде справочников, там места много. Речь идет об учебниках и о знаниях, которые люди получают  помощью этих учебников. Они должны видеть, что все правила логичны, обоснованны, а не выдуманы членами орфографической комиссии. Определенный минимум грамматики позволяет решить все эти проблемы, но никому это не надо. Вот и получается, что учебник - это тот же справочник, только меньшего объема.

Answer (score 2):

Хорошая сказка, только противоречит слегка действительности. Писцы были уважаемыми людьми как раз ДО ТОГО, как правила упростили! А не после. После-то чего их уважать? Раз стало просто, то любой сам себе писец! )))

Comment: Да, Вы, пожалуй, правы. У нашей касты писцов и сейчас всё то же стремление поднять свой престиж  за счет искусственного усложнения письма,всё то же  желание руководить, указывать, втискивать словесность в прокрустово ложе формалистики. Там, где должен действовать ясный и понятный принцип, появляются десятки правил, которые уместнее было бы назвать решенными примерами. Далее принцип  замазывается корректирующим штрихом, а правила предлагаются к  заучиванию.

Comment: Не понимаю я, что такое "искусственное усложнение". Примерчиков бы парочку... И про "ясный и понятный принцип" тоже.

Два ясных и понятных я знаю: первый совсем общий – морфологический принцип. Второй касается слитного/раздельного правописания НЕ. Есть отрицание – раздельно, нет – слитно.
Не разделяю вашего мнения насчёт излишнего усложнения... На Грамме.ру объясняются многие вещи довольно логично. Кто хочет – тот осилит.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что любое правило можно свести к основным принципам и определениям. Если для конкретного правила прослеживается эта связь, то оно логично,что мы можем видеть во многих учебниках, в том числе на Грамоте.ру. Речь же идет о правилах, которые не имеют таких логических связей. Собственно говоря, про каждое  правило можно спросить: а откуда оно взялось? Тогда правила будут не учить, а понимать, а это разные вещи. (Отметим также, что большинство правил родом из грамматики, а это серьезная наука).

Comment: И по поводу слитного/раздельного написания НЕ. Вот справочник Розенталя, там убористым шрифтом на 20 страницах излагаются примерно 50 описательных правил по принципу "если А, то пишем Б". Никакого анализа, одни наблюдения. Наша орфография напоминает мне ботанику до Карла Линнея.

Comment: Так это же спра-воч-ник! Не учебник. Откройте любой справочник – где там общие принципы?

Comment: Ну тогда вот учебник для 10-11 классов, там 30 правил, взятые наугад, текст покороче, вот и вся разница. А ведь эта орфограмма тесно связана не только с морфологией, но и с синтаксисом, потому что фактически мы различаем утвердительные и отрицательные предложения. И общий принцип вы сами сформулировали "есть отрицание – раздельно, нет – слитно". Вот три написания: "комната небольшая/не большая, небольшая комната", при выборе этих трех вариантов можете рассказать, как  этот основной принцип действует?

Comment: Я имею в виду, София?

Comment: Эта комната небольшая/не большая. Принцип действует в чистом виде! Слово "небольшой" в языке есть? Кто хоть немного читает – ответит утвердительно.
Дальше. Хотите отрицать (отрицаете, что большая) – пожалуйте раздельно. Утверждаете, что небольшая (вспоминаем, что слово есть!) – пишем слитно.

"Небольшая комната" – если вне контекста, то, естественно, слитно. Определение, определяемое слово.

Comment: Аксиоматически грамматика не строится, тем более школьная. И если человек не читает книг и не слышит нормальной речи – никакие учебники не помогут.